# Create MVC route for id parameter and for action/id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes

This URL `www.mysite.com/Brazil` should route to this controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CountryPage(string countryName)
```

And countryName should be `Brazil`

I tried using this custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Country",
    "{id}",
    new { controller = "Countries", action = "CountryPage", id = "{id}" });
```

When my controller is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CountryPage(string id)
```

But all I got in the id is `{id}`.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose, you can leverage [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing). To do so, decorate your controller method using the `[Route()]` data annotation as shown below.

***CountryController.cs***

```
[Route("{country}")]
public IActionResult CountryPage(string country)
{
    return Ok(country);
}
```

When accessing `https://localhost:44376/Brazil`, the application returns:

> Brazil